# Type of Link component passed as 'component' prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

I have a Function Component (with TypeScript), let's say it's called Button. I import Button as BaseButton from Material-UI, style it, add some cool fetures (I removed unnecessary code down here) and export it as my own Button. Later, when I use this exported Button somewhere in the code and want to pass Link component (imported from react-router-dom) as a 'component' prop to this button. What type should I use in ButtonProps interface? Also, should 'to' prop be specified as a string?

```
component/button.tsx

import * as React from 'react';
import { Button as BaseButton } from '@material-ui/core';

interface ButtonProps {
  component: ???;
  to: string;
}

export const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({ component, to }) => (
  <BaseButton component={component} to={to} />
)
```

.

```
some other place

import { Button } from 'components/button';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

(...)
  <Button component={Link} to={'/'} />
(...)
```

Comment: `component: React.ReactElement` would do it. But this allows you to input ANY react component then. The prop `to` I would type as: `H.LocationDescriptor` where the import is: `import * as H from "history"`. To restrict the component even further you could add the following type to it: `component: React.Component<Link, unknown>`

Answer (score 0):

< Link > tags are not visual components, but a wrappers made for adding navigation functionality,
material-ui is for the opposite use 
therefore something like this should navigate

---

```
    export const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({ to }) => 
      <Link to={to}
        <BaseButton /> // your own styled compnent
      </Link>
     )
```

---

Comment: I don't quite want to use this solution in my project, since sometimes the button will be a Link, sometimes a regular button, sometimes even a link possibly. But clever idea though :)